# Where do I report Redshift causing Desktop Crash?

Tags: 22.04, crash, mate, redshift

I'm posting this first of all to share in case someone else runs into my problem and second of all to ask where I report the problem more specifically.

Recently I have installed Ubuntu Mate 22.04 on 3 slightly older machines: a Samsung, an Asus, and a Dell. (Hoping to get it on my HP soon.) At least 2 of those 3 installs (definitely the Dell and Asus), possibly all three, had a desktop crashing issue that took awhile to figure out.

After hunting around a lot each time, I discovered each time that redshift seems to be causing the desktop crash. After uninstalling redshift (which was a default install with Ubuntu Mate 22.04), each machine has so far worked wonderfully.

When I could, when prompted, I would report the crashes. But I wanted to post it here both to ask if there was another place I could report it and also so that if someone else looks up desktop crashes (or getting kicked out to the log in screen) they might try uninstalling redshift.

Thanks.

Comment: I would look in `/var/crash` for a .crash file with the time/date that matches the issue you experienced, and report using that file, ie. `ubuntu-bug /var/crash/[filename from directory].crash` .  I'd also peruse that file for some clues as to issue, FYI:  I use redshift & have had no issues; so I'd likely also check your config file doesn't contain errors..

Comment: Thank you for reporting! Bug reports are essential to fixing issues. However, bug reports aren't accepted here. Please file a bug report though official bug reporting channels.  In order for this question to not be closed as a duplicate, it should be rewritten to ask about the actual problem, instead of asking how to file a bug report.

Comment: Very helpful answers - thanks.